# Does a "terminal" always need to run with python

Tags: python

Hi im a bit new to python but i want to learn more my question is when you build a web application and you are going to use python to do the data handling and calculations does this mean in order for that to be used a terminal,in this case lets say on windows will have to run and that basically listens if and when something was triggered or executed on the python program/script

Comment: Could you specific the question you're asking? I think many people are having a difficult time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: No, not on Windows. On it, if a Python script file is run with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` the no console widow will be created. If the script file's extension is `.pyw` instead of `.py`, this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-various-implementations-python/) summarizes how different types of Python run. By default, on many systems, CPython is present. When it interprets `py` files initially, it may create `pyc` files, which can then run on the CPython virtual machine, described [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~brgallar/week9_3.html). The virtual machine and interpreter are also running when you run `python` on your terminal, if you are using this. As described in the first article however, CPython isn't the only way to run Python.